# In SQL Server, is there way to have a field where an auto-number is appended to the end of whatever value the field is set to?

Tags: sql-server

Sorry if that's not overly clear.

In SQL Server, can I have a field which I can place a string into, and then SQL Server appends an auto-number onto the end?

So for example, say I have column A.

- If I set row 1 in column A to "Foo", the final value will be "Foo1"
- Then if I set row 2 in column A to "Bar", the final value is "Bar2"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes use a Calculated Value column. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD ColumnB AS ColumnA + CAST(ID AS varchar(8)) PERSISTED
```

Assuming ID is where you're getting row 1 or row 2 value.

Answer (score 2):

Another a way would be based on a view. If you can't modify the source table - often the case for 3rd party products - a view can save your day. Like so,

```
create table autoappend(id int identity(1,1) , data nvarchar(32))
go
insert into autoappend(data) values ('foo')
insert into autoappend(data) values ('bar')
insert into autoappend(data) values ('zof')
go

create view vAppend as
    select id
        , data
        , appended = data + convert(nvarchar(8), id)  -- concat() is SS2012+ only
    from autoappend
go

select * from vAppend
```

Output:

```
id  data    appended
1   foo foo1
2   bar bar2
3   zof zof3
```

Comment: `appended` is a column alias. I suggest you remove the single quotes.

Comment: @ypercube, Thanks. Didn't remember that. I Guess old [bad habits](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) are hard to kick